# Java ArrayList "forgets" everything

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a program which adds data to the ArrayList. Then from the main menu you can press a button and it shows the entire ArrayList. The problem is that when I fill out the form it will add to the ArrayList, but when you go to the main menu it forgets everything in the ArrayList and it shows up empty.

I know I need to set something (I've done it once before) but I just can't figure it out.

This is the main menu:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class KlantenbindingFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
/**
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
JFrame frame;
private JButton toonKlanten, toonAutos, toonOverzicht, voegKlantToe,
private JPanel contentPane;
private Klantenbinding klantenBindingRef;
private Klant klantRef;
 * Launch the application.
public static void main(String[] args) {

 * Create the frame.
public KlantenbindingFrame() {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//      klantenBindingRef = new Klantenbinding();
    if (e.getSource() == voegKlantToe) {
        KlantToevoegen vkt = new KlantToevoegen();
//          vkt.setKlantenBindingRef(klantenBindingRef);
        vkt.setVisible(true);
//          setVisible(false);
    }

    if (e.getSource() == toonOverzicht) {
        System.out.println(klantenBindingRef.toString());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                klantenBindingRef.toString(),
                "Alle klanten", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }

}

public void setKlantenBindingRef(Klantenbinding klantenBindingRef) {
    this.klantenBindingRef = klantenBindingRef;

}

public void setKlantRef(Klant klantref) {
    this.klantRef = klantref;
}

public void setDeKlant(Klant klantref){
    this.klantRef = klantref;
}

}
```

This is the class in which the ArrayList is stored:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Klantenbinding {
private String naam;
protected List<Klant> alleKlanten = new ArrayList<Klant> ();

public void voegKlantToe(Klant k){
    if (alleKlanten.indexOf(k) == -1){
        alleKlanten.add(k);
    }
}

public List<Klant> getAlleKlanten(){
    return alleKlanten;
}

public void setAlleKlanten(ArrayList<Klant> alleKlanten) {
    this.alleKlanten = alleKlanten;
}

public boolean heeftKlant(String naam) {
    boolean b = false;
    for (Klant k : alleKlanten) {
        if (k.getNaam() == naam) {
            b = true;
        }
    }
    return b;
}

public void verwijderKlant(Klant exKlant) {
    if (heeftKlant(exKlant.getNaam())) {
        alleKlanten.remove(exKlant);
    }
}

public boolean zoekKlant(Klant nweKlant) {
    for (Klant k : alleKlanten) {
        if (k.equals(nweKlant)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public Klant zoekKlant(String naam) {
    Klant antw = null;
    for (Klant k : alleKlanten){
        if (k.getNaam() == naam){
            antw = k;
        }
    }
    return antw;
}

public void verwijderKlant (String naam){
    Klant gezochte = zoekKlant(naam);
    if (gezochte != null){
        alleKlanten.remove(gezochte);
    }
}

public int aantalKlanten() {
    return alleKlanten.size();
}

public String getNaam(){
    return naam;
}

public String toString() {
    String s = "ATD heeft " + aantalKlanten() + " klant(en). \n\n";
    for (Klant k : alleKlanten) {
        s += k + "\n";
    }
    return s;
}
}
```

This is the class in which I add the customer to the ArrayList:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class KlantToevoegen extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
/**
JFrame frame;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JButton voegToe, terug;
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField nmTf, strTf, hnrTf, pcTf, plTf, telnrTf, emailTf;
        lblHuisnr, lblPostcode, lblPlaats, lblTelnr, lblEmail;
private JComboBox<?> aanhefBox;
private Klantenbinding klantenBindingRef;
private JSeparator separator;
private JSeparator separator_1;
private Klant klantref;

 * Launch the application.
public static void main(String[] args) {

 * Create the frame.
public KlantToevoegen() {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String foutmelding = "Controleer of alle gegevens zijn ingevuld";
    String naam = nmTf.getText();
    String straat = strTf.getText();
    String huisnummer = hnrTf.getText();
    String postcode = pcTf.getText();
    String plaats = plTf.getText();
    String telefoonnummer = telnrTf.getText();
    String email = emailTf.getText();
    boolean allesoke = true;
    klantenBindingRef = new Klantenbinding();

    if (e.getSource() == terug) {
        KlantenbindingFrame kbf = new KlantenbindingFrame();
        kbf.setKlantenBindingRef(klantenBindingRef);
        setVisible(false);
    }

    if (e.getSource() == voegToe) {
        if ("".equals(naam) || "".equals(straat) || "".equals(huisnummer)
                || "".equals(postcode) || "".equals(plaats)
                || "".equals(telefoonnummer) || "".equals(email)) {

            allesoke = false;
            foutmelding += "\n";
        }

        if (allesoke) {
            klantref = new Klant(nmTf.getText());
            klantenBindingRef.voegKlantToe(klantref);
            System.out.println(naam + straat + huisnummer + klantenBindingRef.toString());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Klant toegevoegd" + naam,
                    "Toegevoegd",   JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null);
            terugHoofdmenu();



        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, foutmelding,      "Foutmelding",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null);
        }
    }
}

private void terugHoofdmenu() {
    setVisible(false);
    KlantenbindingFrame kf1 = new KlantenbindingFrame();
    kf1.setKlantenBindingRef(klantenBindingRef);
    kf1.setKlantRef(klantref);
}

public void setKlantenBindingRef(Klantenbinding klantenBindingRef){
    this.klantenBindingRef = klantenBindingRef;
}

public void setDeKlant(Klant klantref){
    this.klantref = klantref;
}

}
```

And finally the class for the customer:

```
public class Klant {
private String naam;

public Klant(String naam) {
    this.naam = naam;
}

public String getNaam(){
    return naam;
}

public void setNaam(String naam){
    this.naam = naam;
}

}
```

Comment: None of this code mentions `ArrayList`.

Comment: where is the `ArrayList`?

Comment: Sounds like a scope issue. Is the object you're adding items to the same object in your main menu?

Comment: `ArrayList` is magic! So, did you do a get and set? . Take your alleKlanten with the get method, add items or work with it. Then use the set method to save changes.

Comment: @above: don't use the set method to save changes

Comment: @MartinCarney I don't add anything in my main menu, everything is in a different class but the ArrayList doesn't save the list when I go back to the menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't forget anything. It's just that you create a new empty(!) ArrayList to show in your Menu:

```
klantenBindingRef = new Klantenbinding();
                    ^^^
System.out.println(klantenBindingRef.toString());
```

You need to use the same object instance which you initialized before...

Another (not so nice) option is to use a static ArrayList

```
protected static List<Klant> alleKlanten = new ArrayList<Klant> ();
```

Or to use the [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Btw: your `setAlleKlanten` function is dangerous: it really has the potential to make your list forget everything (because it just replaces everyting which already exists in your list)

Comment: Ok... but how? Because when I don't use that I get a nullpointer

Comment: @Dyon Sorry but I can't tell you that without seeing the complete code

Comment: I changed the begin post. Making is static is not an option, it's a school assignment and my teacher specifically told us not to make anything static...

Comment: @Dyon In your local language (probably Dutch?), your code is hard to read for me, but I still try: You have declarations of `klantenBindingRef` everywhere, and some `new Klantenbinding()`. Make sure you only have _one_ `new` (which is initialized somewhere when initializing your first JFrame) and not more than one `klantenBindingRef` variables per class. Use a setter function or a constructor to copy the reference of this single `Klantenbinding` instance to other classes

Comment: Thank you, I declared it in the constructor and changed visibility and now it works. Thank you!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't tell your teacher that you cheated and have nice evening ;-)